# Replace the # values present in a column in pandas dataframe with auto-incremental values by rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

The scenario is: VendorID column contains '#' in all rows of pandas dataframe.
I have been trying to substitute the value of '#' in VendorID column to the auto increment row number value.

I was trying str.replace() function :

```
data['VendorID'].str.replace(r'[#]', replacing_value)
```

I am trying to figure out what should i write in place of replacing_value, in the above line

Currently its showing like:

```
VendorID
#
#
#
.
.
```

Expected:

```
VendorID
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['VendorID']= pd.Series(range(1,df.shape[0]+1)) #starts with 1
```

or

```
df['VendorID']= pd.Series(range(0,df.shape[0])) #starts with 0
```

Comment: It gave a good workaround. Performing: data['VendorID'] = pd.Series(range(1,len(data['VendorID'])+1)) added an additional column called index as well, but dropping that index column satisfied the requirement. Thanks.

Comment: If the solution helped you, try up-voting & accepting the answer